# rtl support and configuration with semantic ui react

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, right-to-left, semantic-ui-react, stepper

I am using Semantic UI lib for react
https://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction.
and create-react-app boilerplate 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app.
My app requires RTL support especially for the Step component. 
while researching for a solution i found that semantic ui have a config file semantic.json where i can define RTL but i can't warp the whole thing together.
does anyone have any recommendation or best practice for that?

Answer (score 3):

you can use this

```css
.ui * {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The RTL support is a function of the `semantic-ui` CSS styles and should not have anything to do with `semantic-ui-react`. If you compile your own styles using the build tools in `semantic-ui` then use those styles in your project, they will work.

If you don't want to compile your own RTL styles, I believe this CDN is hosting a compiled RTL version of the CSS:

http://rtlcss.com/cdn/css-frameworks/semantic-ui/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the end I build Semantic RTL style in separate project and then use it as a static file in my project .

Comment: @onn glad to hear you took the first option to solve this by compiling your own styles. Please consider marking the answer correct if it was the right one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `semantic-ui` in `reactjs` in `RTL` language such *(Persian/Arabic)*,  you can follow below steps.

**With** `cdn`

First install semantic-ui for reactjs:

```
npm i semantic-ui-react
```

Then install semantic-ui css:

```
npm i semantic-ui-css
```

Now include semantic-ui rtl in `index.html` (just css)

**[Semantic UI RTL](https://rtlcss.com/cdn/css-frameworks/semantic-ui/index.html)**

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.rtl.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-yXUIpeQfH3cuk6u6Mwu8uyJXB2R3UOLvcha1343UCMA2TA7lQ14BFmrudI6LAP8A"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**Without** `cdn` *(Recommended)*

If you don't want use cdn, just download `css` [file](https://cdn.rtlcss.com/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.rtl.min.css) go to this path:

> node_modules/semanti-ui-css/

Put this css here, where semantic.css is, then include this:

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.rtl.min.css';
```

*This method tested and already work fine, if anyone had issue, feel free to comment and I'll respond.*

Comment: installing npm package (semantic-ui-css) is useless in your solution as you'll end up using the CDN version (through cdn or by downloading it locally)